# importing plugin for neo4j in grails failing

Tags: grails, neo4j

I created a grails project but it doesn't seem to recognize the plugin I have installed:

```
import grails.plugins.neo4j.Neo4jEntity
@Neo4jEntity
class Author {
  String name
  Date dob

  static hasMany = [ books: Book ]
}
```

Was this changed to something else?

I initially did:

```
grails create-app neo4jtest; cd neo4jtest
grails install-plugin neo4j
grails create-domain-class Author
grails create-domain-class Book
grails create-controller Author
grails create-controller Book
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Neo4jEntity` is no longer supported in 1.x series of the plugin. It was the way to go in 0.x version which were not GORM compliant.
If you're using multiple datastores, you can use

```
static mapWith = "neo4j"
```

to indicate a domain being persisted in Neo4j. If there's only one datastore this is not necessary.